# Selecting Color Value With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my options form I have a few color inputs that I would like to have load their preset values, but currently it won't select and display the value that it is given.

The Html:

```
    <h3 class="option">Search Bar Background Color:</h3>
    <input type="color" class="color searchBarBackground" id="barBackground" name="searchBarBackground">

    <h3 class="option">Search Bar Placeholder Text Color:</h3>
    <input type="color" class="color searchBarPlaceholder" id="placeColor" name="searchBarPlaceholder">

    <h3 class="option">Search Bar Text Color:</h3>
    <input type="color" class="color searchBarText" id="barColor" name="searchBarText">

    <h3 class="option">Go Button Background Color:</h3>
    <input type="color" class="color goButtonBackground" id="goBackground" name="goButtonBackground">
```

The Javascript Load Function:

```
window.onLoad = loadOptions();

function loadOptions() {
    var defaultBarBackground = '#000000';
    var defaultGoBackground = '#000000';
    var defaultBarColor = '#ffffff';
    var defaultPlaceColor = '#999999';

    chrome.storage.local.get('barBackgroundOption', function (x) { 
        $('#barBackground').attr("value", x.barBackgroundOption);
    });
    chrome.storage.local.get('barColorOption', function (x) {
        $('#barColor').attr("value", x.barColorOption);
    });
    chrome.storage.local.get('placeColorOption', function (x) { 
        $('#placeColor').attr("value", x.placeColorOption);
    });
    chrome.storage.local.get('goBackgroundOption', function (x) { 
        $('#goBackground').attr("value", x.barBackgroundOption);

    });
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is simply selecting that value, because when I inspect the element on the page it has the right value - it just doesn't display it.

Comment: [jQuery.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)?

Comment: Haha well that did it... da** jquery... thanks :)

Comment: For the record, you should collapse that in a single call to `get`: make an object with key-default value pairs and pass that to `get`, i.e. `{defaultBarBackground: '#000000', /*...*/}`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the code before the page loads. You are not assigning the method to the onload, you are assigning what is returned to it.

```
window.onLoad = loadOptions();
                           ^^
```

needs to be

```
window.onLoad = loadOptions;
```

Also seems weird that you are using `attr()` to set the value. And you really should not be using .onload to set something to load onload, that is bad practice. Since you are using jQuery, use

```
$(window).on("load", loadOptions);
```

without jQuery, you would use `addEventListener()`